# El array enviado mediante ajax me da fallos

Tags: php, javascript, ajax

[image: Funcion Onclick de mi formulario]

Hola buenas , tengo un problema ,yo paso un array por ajax con esta funcion hacia un controlador en laravel y sus valores los quiero almacenar en una base de datos, el problema ue tengo esque en cuando ejecuto la consulta de base de datos el sistema casca y solo me saca el primer valor del vector si hay suerte por que la segunda vez que pulso el boton ni eso , sin embargo si no esta la consulta a la base de datos lo imprimo con echo y va genial , pero asi no puedo guardar nada , me podrian ayudar?. [image: consulta en el controlador de laravel]

Comment: ¿Podrías compartir el código copiando y pengando? En imagen es incómodo para poder reproducirlo y sugerirte cambios (te puedo proponer dos soluciones).

Answer (score 0):

Elimina esta linea:

```
var frase = JSON.stringify(album);
```

Reemplaza esta linea:

```
$.post(url, {data : frase}, function(msg) {
```

Por esto:

```
$.post(url, {data : album}, function(msg) {
```

Así desde tu controlador ya podrías utilizar

```
$_POST['data'];
```

como lo requieras.

Comment: Vale muchas gracias todos ya di con el fallo

Answer (score 0):

Intenta cambiando:

```
var frase = JSON.stringify(album);
```

Por

```
var frase = JSON.parse(album);
```

Esto te deberá de retornar el array completo